# Querying JSON with JS (using unknown parent)

Tags: javascript, json

Lets says we have an object that looks like this.

```
    // first name - of employee 3
    company.employees.employeeId[3].first


    // last name - of employee 3
    company.employees.employeeId[3].last


    // department - of employee 3
    company.employees.employeeId[3].department
```

is there a way/library to do a query like this

```
    // looking for all employees in department Z
    result = company.employees.[*].department['accounting']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them:

```
var result = company.employees.employeeID.filter(function(employee) {
    return employee.department === 'accounting';
});
```

Comment: would that work with multiple filters?

var result = company.employees.filter(function(employee) {
    return employee.department === 'accounting';
}).filter(function(somethingElse) {
    return somethingElse.thing === 'abc';
});

Comment: @MilkMan - Yes, or you could just add their logic to the callback.

Comment: you passed employee to the function... would that have to be the parent key?

Comment: @MilkMan: `employee` is an element of `company.employees.employeeID` (assuming that's an array).

Comment: @MilkMan: The result is an array of objects, not a single object.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Using the test object in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BceK3/1/) how would I find all test.item.obj.a = 6... please update the fiddle if you could. Thank you in advance for you help. I can barely understand what I'm asking, so hats off to you for interpreting it logically.